# Binary search, strcmp two dynamic arrays of strings in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, binary-search, strcmp

I'm fairly new to C programming but trying my best to understand it. I have two dynamic strings that are populated from two plain text files. One being a form of a dictionary, and the other one just a user input. What I want to get is binary search each user input word in the dictionary and find out if it is present (sort of a spell checker I guess).

I'm stuck on my binary search function:

```
char **dictElem;
int dictSize;
char **inputElem;

int binsearch(const char *val){
  int pos;
  int beg=0;
  int end=dictSize-1;
  int cond=0;

  while (beg<=end){
    pos=(beg+end)/2; //Jump in the middle
    if ((cond=strcmp(dictElem[pos],val)) == 0)
      return pos;
    else if (cond<0)
      beg=pos+1;
    else
      end=pos-1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Both `dictElem` and `inputElem` were already read by other methods and (let's say) both [0] elements are equal strings `"aa"`.

However after I run the `binsearch(inputElem[0]` it always returns 0. I tried just `strcmp(dictElem[0],inputElem[0])` and it returns 1.

Where am I going wrong? Is it comparing char** and char*?

**UPD:**
Function that's loading the `dictElem`

```
void readd(FILE *file){
  int i=0,size=0; /* local size */
  char line[1024]; /* Local array for a single word read */
  printf("Loadingn dict...\n");
  while ((fgets(line,sizeof(line),file))!=NULL){
    dictElem=(char**)realloc(dictElem,(size+1)*sizeof(char *));
    dictElem[size++]=strdup(line);
  }
  printf("Total elements loaded: %d\n",size);
}
```

Function that reads a user file is very similar, just a little different format.

Comment: Try running your sort function on arrays of integers, if it works correctly move on to strings.

Comment: Can you show us code where you are assigning `dictElem` and `val`?

Comment: Also, the algorithm is called "Binary search", not "Binary TREE search", because there is no binary tree, just a sorted array.

Comment: You're absolutely right, my mistake.

Comment: I think a `readd` is reading a newline character into `dictElem` array, so of course comparing it with a exactly the same string without newline char is very silly. Just going to check it

Comment: Consider using the built-in `bsearch` library function which will perform a binary search for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is in this line `if ((cond=strcmp(dictElem[pos],val) == 0))`. This line of code assigns the result of expression `strcmp(dictElem[pos], val) == 0` to the variable `cond`, and then checks whether cond is zero or not. 
I guess your original intent was to store in `cond` the result of `strcmp`, so you should move the closing parenthesis before `==`. The correct line is `if ((cond = strcmp(dictElem[pos], val) == 0)`.

There are some other problems with your code:

1. 0 is used as special not-found value, but in the same time 0 can be
   returned when element is found at index 0.
2. Using `char *val`, when
   it is better to use `const char *val`, because contents of this
   string aren't going to be modified. It is always better to write const-correct code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There is definitely an error with the parentheses. But the corrected line that you suggested leaves the if statement condition open. Although Carey Gregory appears to be right about that line `if ((cond=strcmp(dictElem[pos],val)) == 0)` I have also changed the char to constant as you suggested.

Comment: Although the function still returns `0` regardless of the `val` i give it.

Comment: It works for me(although I manually asssigned values to dictElem). I guess the problem is that you don't set dictSize. If not, then please check if your dictionary is sorted.

Comment: Because a dictionary file should be replaceable, I can't specify the array size. The dictionary is definitely sorted. Would a `\n` character in `dictElem` matter?

Comment: But can't you just write `dictSize = size` in your dictionary loading function? You definitely need `dictSize` in `binsearch()` function. As for newlienes, yes, they do matter, you should manually trim it, for some string s: `s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0'`. Also, you'll need to manually concat strings, if words in your dictionary are (for some reason) are longer than 1023 characters.

Comment: Okay, i've got some more ideas now. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
if ((cond=strcmp(dictElem[pos],val) == 0))
```

The parentheses are giving it the wrong order of evaluation and cond will always end up 0 or 1 (because you're assigning the results of the comparison strcmp() == 0 to it).  Try this instead:

```
if ((cond=strcmp(dictElem[pos],val)) == 0)
```